# SQLite, Android : Can I bypass the call cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME) if I know the ColumnIndex?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a newbie in Android. For cursor handling I find a debate and that confuses me.
Let us consider the call

```
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "my_column_name";
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
```

Now I am reading a debate that cursor.getColumnIndex function is adding overhead to the cursor loop and therefore be called before the loop. (There is a counter argument that recent coding has placed a one time map ). Is this index implicitly created when I am creating the table and hence I am forced to call it? And if so, isn't it counterproductive ?

OR

This index is a map of column names only and the first column is 0, second column is 1 and so on and therefore if I know the create statement syntax for the table, I can easily identify the column index myself?

I would be very much pleased to be guided to further notes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This index is a map of column names only and the first column is 0,
> second column is 1 and so on and therefore if I know the create
> statement syntax for the table, I can easily identify the column index
> myself?

The answer to the above question is **Yes**.

Well, you can pass the index directly to `cursor.getString` or any other respective methods but you should call `cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)` just to be safe so that you are not giving the wrong index to the cursor. So you can do one thing, call the `cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)` and store the index in a variable before the loop starts, and in the loop use that variable which holds the value of the index.

Well my recommendation is to use room persistence library for sqlite, sooner or later you will fall in love with it.

Comment: Hi Suraj. I am reading a lot about Room Persistence. I guess this is a simplified version of DAO interfaces like hibernate in java architecture. However I am not sure about the android version backward compatibility of Room Persistence.

Comment: I don't think it will give you any pain for compatibility, use it without hesitation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this index implicitly created when I am creating the table...

A `Cursor` object instance is not directly related to a table.
It is the result of a **query** that contains much more info than the rows and the column values, such as the number of the rows, the names of the columns and the index of each column inside the resultset.
Not all queries are as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

You can query a single table and fetch the columns in any order that you want if you enumerate them in a special order in the `SELECT` list, or omit columns that you don't want:

```
SELECT column2, column4, column1 FROM tablename
```

Or you can query multiple tables with joins and return some of their columns:

```
SELECT t1.somecolumn, t2.othercolumn FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ...
```

So don't think that a `Cursor` represents the contents of a table and this is why you should always use `getColumnIndex()`.
Even when you are doing the simplest of the queries like the one at the top of this answer, because it is safer and it always works.

Maybe this adds more burden when you are iterating through all the rows and columns of the query, but in this case you can store the indices of the columns in variables before the loop and use the variables inside the loop.

The only case that I may not use `getColumnIndex()` is with a single column resultset, because in that case I'm sure that a call to `getString(0)` will work.